# PHPFox - GetBlock - Javascript Does not execute after getContent

Tags: javascript, popup, phpfox

I am using phpfox v3.7 script. i have an issue of executing javascript, when i load a block using getBlock method.

I am calling this getblock method from the service file which in turn gets called by an ajax function.  i am following the below mentioned sequence for the actions.

1. The controller loads the initial module A,
2. On Module A, calling another Module B,
3. On click of a button in module B, using ajax call, i am executing a service and within that calling getBlock method.

The Block which gets the content has javascripts , which does not get executed once the block is loaded on the targeted page.

Comment: welcome to SO , you should know that members of this community work so hard to help others , and the least to be expected from a question author is to spend some time preparing his question and putting some code and additional information to help find the problem faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. well try to use your javascript code in the literal tag like

   ```
         {literal} //your javascript code here{/literal}
   ```

   if you are failed to load the main javascript library in the block template   file,   use direct path
   to your javascript file in the template,i mean include that js
   library in the block template itself

   Hope this solution will definately work

Comment: Thanks Bharat, use of direct path in this scenario has resolved the issue.